# Reducer that returns a collection of reducer results

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a reducer that looks like this:

```
const chart = combineReducers({
    data,   
    fetchProgress,
    fetchError,
    updateProgress,
    updateError,
});
```

I now would like to not only a chart but multiple charts.

```
const charts = (state = {}, action = {}) => {
    if (action.type == FETCH_CHART || action.type == ...) { 
        let newChart = chart(state[action.id], action);
        return Object.assign({}, state, {[action.id]: newChart});
    }
    return state;
}
```

Is there something conceptually wrong to do this?

If no, is there a better way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the concept. In fact, I'd say this is my preferred approach when needing to store similar data in the redux store

To improve it, you could wrap it in a higher-order reducer to handle the `id` part of it.  Something like:

```
const handleIds = (reducer) => (state = {}, action) => {
    if (action.id) {
        let idState = state[action.id]
        let newState = reducer(idState, action)

        if (newState !== idState) {
            return  { ...state, [action.id]: newState }
        }
    }

    return state
}
```

This will pass on any action with an `id` and merge the resulting `state` into it's `state` with that `id` as it's key, if the `state` has changed.

Then your reducer becomes:

```
const singleChart = (state = {}, action = {}) => {
    if (action.type == FETCH_CHART || action.type == ...) { 
        let newChart = chart(state, action);
        return newChart;
    }
    return state;
}

const charts = handleIds(singleChart)
```

Then combine it into your store:

```
const chart = combineReducers({
    data,   
    fetchProgress,
    fetchError,
    updateProgress,
    updateError,
    charts
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would breakdown the logic to further sub reducers in order to have a better **separation of concerns**. In case you will add multiple charts and in case you will need to add more logic/settings/data to your actions, you will end up to modify too much your single reducer.

I follow with a small example where you could have 3 charts.

```
// bubbleChartReducer.js
export function bubble (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_BUBBLE_CHART': 
      return {
        [action.id]: new chart(action.id, action)
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// pieChartReducer.js
export function pie (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_PIE_CHART': 
      return {
        [action.id]: new chart(action.id, action)
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

// linearChartReducer.js
export function pie (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_LINEAR_CHART': 
      return {
        [action.id]: new chart(action.id, action)
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}



// chartsReducer.js
import { bubble } from 'bubbleChartReducer'
import { pie } from 'pieChartReducer'
import { linear } from 'linearChartReducer'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

export combineReducers({
  bubble,
  pie,
  linear
})
```